# noob react number | number[] type problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm really new with react and javascript, and I have a small thing I don't understand and it's really blocking me.

I have a range slider with 2 values so I take these value in the variable
`myValue` of type number | number[]

Then when I console.log the value, everything seems ok (I have an array with the good value)

But when I want to use my value
`let minVal = myValue[0]` create an error

And `myValue` doesn't accept `.length` `.typeOf` or anything to do this kind of condition test:

```
   let [minVal, maxVal] = (myValue.length==2) ? myValue : [myValue, myValue];
```

I really don't understand what is wrong with what I wrote. It seems so basic but I'm reaaly blocked.
Could you explain how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the union operator, you indicate that `myValue` can either be a `number` or a `number[]`.
Now obviously both of them will not have the same properties.
Methods like `toString()`, `valueOf()` exist in both, as they do in most javascript variables but `.length` is array specific and TS really cannot let you access that value.

You can do this :

```
 let [minVal, maxVal] = (Array.isArray(myValue) && myValue.length==2) ? myValue : [myValue, myValue];
```

Putting a `typeguard` so TS does not complain